# Get first element of array of pairs (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift

I have this array:

```
let arrayOfPairs = [
    (8, 1),
    (6, 4),
    (2, 3),
]
```

I want this array:

```
let arrayOfSingleValues = [
    8,
    6,
    2,
]
```

How do I pull a value out of a pair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use map to get just the first element of your tuple as follow:

```
let arrayOfPairs = [(8, 1), (6, 4), (2, 3)]
let arrayOfSingleValues = arrayOfPairs.map { $0.0 }

print(arrayOfSingleValues)   // [8, 6, 2]
```